# What is the best method to store an Array in an app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing a Google Forms Script and need to save extra information about each question. I was thinking about an array to PropertiesService with the question ID as the label, but apparently only strings can be saved.

-bj

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse to easily convert array to string and reverse.